# Vue Router default child route not loading initially

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I've setup a simple Vue (with vue-router and Vuetify) project and I'm trying to get the default child route to load when the parent route is accessed.

I've done my best to follow the Vue docs to do this, but the default child route, simply won't load when I access it's parent.

Here's the code in `router.js` file:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'

import Home from './views/Home'
import Details from './views/Details'
import List from './views/List'
import NotFound from './views/NotFound'
import Secondary from './views/Secondary'
import Sections from './views/Sections'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'route.home',
      component: Home
    },
    {
      path: '/list',
      name: 'route.list',
      component: List
    },
    {
      props: true,
      path: '/sections/:id',
      name: 'route.sections',
      component: Sections,
      children: [
        {
          alias: '',
          path: 'details',
          name: 'route.details',
          component: Details
        },
        {
          path: 'secondary',
          name: 'route.secondary',
          component: Secondary
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      path: '*',
      name: 'route.notfound',
      component: NotFound
    }
  ]
})
```

And here's a link to the CodeSandbox.io project:
https://codesandbox.io/s/l41zk6olqz

If you follow these steps in the sandbox you'll see what's happening:

1. When on the *Home* page, click the **Go to List** link
2. On the *List* page, click the **Go to Sections** link
3. When the *Sections* page loads, I'm expecting the default child route (named `route.details` to load), however, it doesn't

The *Details* page does load if you click the **Details** link in the tabs list.
I'm sure this is a simple error, but I can't see the wood for the trees.

### Thanks in advance.

Update (2019-04-03 @ 07:00):
Some further digging, and the following seems to work:
`router.js`

```js
...
  {
      props: true,
      path: '/sections/:id',
      // name: 'route.sections',
      component: Sections,
      children: [
        {
          alias: '',
          path: 'details',
          name: 'route.details',
          component: Details
        },
        {
          path: 'secondary',
          name: 'route.secondary',
          component: Secondary
        }
      ]
    }
...
```

And then changing the `router-link` from `:to="{ name: 'route.sections', params: { id: 1 } }"` to `:to="{ name: 'route.details', params: { id: 1 } }"`
Now resolves the default child route.
Is this expected?
I got the info from this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50065601/9127864

Update (2019-04-03 @ 07:28):
Even further digging shows that this is also possible:
`router.js`

```js
...
  {
      props: true,
      path: '/sections/:id',
      name: 'route.sections',
      component: Sections,
      redirect: {
        name: 'route.details'
      },
      children: [
        {
          alias: '',
          path: 'details',
          name: 'route.details',
          component: Details
        },
        {
          path: 'secondary',
          name: 'route.secondary',
          component: Secondary
        }
      ]
    }
...
```

Then I can change the `router-link` back to `:to="{ name: 'route.sections', params: { id: 1 } }"` and the default child route now loads when the user accesses the parent router.

Hopefully this will help someone else in the future.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's what I've found to work:

```js
...
  {
      props: true,
      path: '/sections/:id',
      name: 'route.sections',
      component: Sections,
      redirect: {
        name: 'route.details'
      },
      children: [
        {
          alias: '',
          path: 'details',
          name: 'route.details',
          component: Details
        },
        {
          path: 'secondary',
          name: 'route.secondary',
          component: Secondary
        }
      ]
    }
...
```

Adding in **`redirect: { name: 'route.details' }`** now makes the parent route redirect to the chosen child route.

Comment: I see you found the answer yourself. You should mark it as the correct answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: @Kordonme - I will, in 2 days :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's in the way you route the sections from the list route. I have worked out on your problem and this is my solution.

For the List.vue redirection to sections.

```
<router-link :to="`/sections/${1}/`">Go to Sections</router-link>
```

Comment: Hi Kyle - it turns out that it's down to the parent route having a name, and the `router-link` needed to point to the default child route. See - https://stackoverflow.com/a/50065601/9127864
I'm still curious as to whether it is possible to have a `route-link` point to the parent route, and then the parent route redirects to the default child route.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect from the parent route to the child route:

```
redirect: {
   name: 'route.details'
}
```

It's also possible to simply remove the `name` property from the parent and move it to the first child. That might spike some confusion so I'd go with option 1.

```
{
  alias: '',
  path: 'details',
  name: 'route.sections',
  component: Details
}
```