# Render default child vue-router 4

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3

I'd like to ask about render default child for view.
I know that exists [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55484090/vue-router-default-child-route-not-loading-initially) with a similar problem but I'm pretty sure that it was for VUE2 and older vue-router. I'm having trouble rendering the default child for view Category. When I'd go to `<router-link :to="{ name: routeName, params: { category: item.id } }`
everything render okay except `<router-view />` it's empty...

I came up with a solution with beforeUpdate(),beforeCreate() but it seems like reinventing the wheel.
If I go to /category/{id} then to /category/{id}/room/{id} and go back one page, the default view will be rendered

How to make the default child load after going to /category/{id}?

*router.js*

```
{
  path: '/category/:category',
  name: 'Category',
  props: true,
  component: Category,
  children: [
    {
      path: '',
      name: 'FavouriteDevicesInCategory',
      component: Devices,
      props: true,
    },
    {
      path: 'room/:room',
      name: 'Devices',
      component: Devices,
      props: true,
    },
  ],
},
```

*Category.vue* - view

```
<template>
  <div class="control">
    <div class="left">
      [...]
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <router-view />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['category', 'room'],
  /** generate default router-view */
  beforeUpdate() {
    this.$router.push('');
  },
  beforeCreate() {
    this.$router.push('');
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution, a little messy, but it seems to be the best solution to this problem

```
{
  path: '/category/:category',
  // name: 'Category',
  props: true,
  component: Category,
  children: [
    {
      path: '',
      name: 'Category',
      component: Devices,
      props: true,
    },
    {
      path: 'room/:room',
      name: 'Devices',
      component: Devices,
      props: true,
    },
  ],
},
```

Answer (score 0):

If your default component is `Category`, you have to create the routes like this:

```
{
  path: '/category',
  name: 'Category',
  props: true,
  component: Category,
  children: [
    {
      path: '/:categoryId',
      name: 'FavouriteDevicesInCategory',
      component: Devices,
      props: true,
    },
    {
      path: 'room/:roomId',
      name: 'Devices',
      component: Devices,
      props: true,
    },
  ],
},
```

By default it will render the `Category` component and if you add an `id` to the url it will go the the `Devices` component

Comment: Thanks, but not exactly the point.
I'll extend a little bit: I have view `Category` in left panel in right panel have `router-view`
And I would love to have that scenario: 
- I go to /category/categoryId
- It generates a view on the left (fixed) menu, on the right in `router-view` it generates a default view named `FavouriteDevicesInCategory`
- I select a room from the left menu
- go to /category/categoryId/room/roomId
-generates a view on the left (fixed) menu, on the right a component named 'Devices'

I don't want to access to /category - without id