# VueJS: Why is my child route/component only rendering after I refresh the page?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I am having trouble getting a child component to render when I click on it's parent component.

When I click on a link to go to my "settings" page, my `SettingsSummaryPage` is rendered, but I'd also like `SettingsPage` component to be rendered as well—as a child.

I think I have things set up correctly—my `routes.js` file looks like this:

```
...

{
    path: '/settings',
        name: 'app.settings.summary',
        component: () =>
            import(
                /* webpackChunkName: 'app.settings.summary' */ '@/views/settings/SettingsSummaryPage.vue'
            ),
        meta: { requiresAuth: true },
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                name: 'app.settings',
                component: () =>
                    import(
                        /* webpackChunkName: 'app.settings' */ '@/views/settings/SettingsPage.vue'
                    ),
                meta: { requiresAuth: true },
            },
        ],
    },

...
```

My `SettingsSummary.vue` component looks like this:

```
<template>
    <div class="flex h-full flex-1 xl:overflow-hidden">
        <SettingsNavigation />

        <router-view />
    </div>
</template>
```

And my `SettingsPage.vue` component looks like this:

```
<template>
    <p>Settings page works!</p>
</template>
```

So what I am expecting to see when I click on a link to "settings" is a page that has my navigation along with "Settings page works!" off to the side.

All of this works great if I click my `/settings` link -- then totally refresh the page.
How can I get my `SettingsPage` component to render *without* refreshing the page?

Answer (score 0):

After finding the correct goole search term(s) I stumbled across [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55484090/vue-router-default-child-route-not-loading-initially) thread.

The route(s) & component(s) are configured correctly, what I was doing wrong was linking to the incorrect route.

Using the above as an example, to get the "settings" page to render, instead of using `app.settings.summary` as the `:to` link, I needed to link to the child. In this case, `app.settings`.

You'll also want to go back and remove the `name` from the parent route. Again, using the above as an example, you'll wan to remove:

```
name: app.settings.summary
```

If you leave the name, you'll get an error in the console.